# Confusion on loops in java

Tags: java, for-loop

Which one is faster in java ?

```
a)  for(int i = 100000; i > 0; i--) {}
b)  for(int i = 1; i < 100001; i++) {}
```

I have been looking for explanation to the answer which is option a, anyone? any help is appreciated

Comment: Answering "which is faster" should be pretty easy, no? (Although since there are no side-effects, who knows, a JVM might optimize it out of existence.)

Comment: Are you saying that "A" is definitively faster than "B"?

Comment: It depends among other things on what processor it will run on. For some, the impact of comparing to a non-zero constant incurs a nontrivial cost (IIRC some versions of the PDP had this). In such case, A would be faster unless the JVM can rewrite B to A. Usually the difference, if any, will be tiny.

Comment: @sum2000 How did you come to this conclusion?

Comment: Cause it was asked by my java professor.Obviously, there is a logic here which i am missing, he gave the answer, asking for explanation

Comment: @downvoter: what in the world is wrong with this question.?

Comment: @sum2000 case B needs an explicit comparison if implemented "literally". Case A may use the flags of the decrement. There's absolutely no guarantee that that will be what the JVM *actually* does, though.

Comment: A lot depends on what you are doing in the loop. If the loop is empty you can remove it so only non-empty loops are interesting.  For example, accessing memory backwards is slower than accessing it forwards. (Due to the way cache lines fill up)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are situations when a reverse loop might be slightly faster in Java. Here's a [benchmark](http://www.mkyong.com/java/reverse-loop-versus-forward-loop-in-performance-java/) showing an example. Typically, the difference is explained by implementation details in the increment/decrement instructions or in the loop-termination comparison instructions, both in the context of the underlying processor architecture. In more complex examples, reversing the loop can help eliminate dependencies and thus enable other optimizations, or can improve memory locality and caching, even garbage collection behavior.

One can not assume that either kind of loop will always be faster, for all cases - a benchmark would be needed to determine which one performs better on a given platform, for a concrete case. And I'm not even considering what the JIT compiler has to do with this.

Anyway, this is the sort of micro-optimizations that can make code more difficult to read, without providing a noticeable performance boost. And so it's better to avoid them unless strictly necessary, remember - "premature optimization is the root of all evil".

Comment: At a guess, I'd say that benchmark is only going faster because the last bit of the array is still in the cache. / In particular not that the 10 million and 15 million runs both have exactly the same (31 ms) time difference between forward and reverse runs.

Comment: "premature optimization is the root of all evil" is worth to quote **again**!

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline what array?

Comment: That "benchmark" is straight out of the "How to not benchmark in Java" book isn't it? Now comparing to 0 is faster on some architectures than compared to other comparisons, but after some loop unrolling we're talking about a handful cycles at most - that's below the accuracy for the usual available timers (~15ms under windows iirc and about the same for linux usually if you can't use the hw regs)

Answer (score 2):

Just talking out of my hat, but I know assembly languages have specific comparisons to zero that take fewer cycles than comparisons between registered values.

Comment: Typically the decrement instruction can set the flags, so you don't need a comparison instruction. Also you'd need the value to compare, although that is likely to be placed in a register for a short loop (and not really matter in a long loop).

Answer (score 1):

Generally, Oracle HotSpot has an emphasis on optimisation in real code, which means that forward loop optimisations are more likely to be implemented than backward loops. From a machine code point of view, the decrementing loop may save an instruction, but it is unlikely to have a significant impact on performance, particularly when there is much memory access going on. I understand modern CPUs are more or less as happy going backwards as forwards (historically there was a time when they were better optimised for forward access). They'll even optimise certain stride access patterns.

(Also HotSpot (at least the Server/C2 flavour) is capable of removing empty loops.)

Answer (score 0):

You told that the answer is a so, I guess an answer: java virtual machine will "translate" the comparison with zero in a faster way.