# Which for loop is faster in java and why

Tags: java

From the following for loops, which one is faster in java

1. `for(int i = 100000; i > 0; i--) {}`
2. `for(int i = 1; i < 100001; i++) {}`

Please provide the valuable reason for the speed. This really helps me in improving the performance of my application.

Comment: I can't say for sure, but I think the JVM will optimize something like this regardless of what you use

Comment: If you can measure the difference, I'll buy you a muffin.

Comment: "This really helps me in improving the performance of my application" - no, it won't.

Comment: [Benchmark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benchmark_%28computing%29) will tell you.

Comment: In *older* JVMs I believe the decrement i-- was "very minutely but measurably faster" (I have no idea how it is on *modern* JVMs) because of a simpler check. In any case, *do not worry about it* because anything inside the loop will dominate the times and the rest of the program will likely dominate the loop :-) (In this case I am assume the statements are not optimized away.)

Comment: Oddly enough, the second loop seems to be 6-10 times as fast as the first.  I just made a simple application which prints the time to loop through each loop, and I'm averaging at 800,000 nanoseconds for the first for loop, and 90,000 for the second.  Code pasted at http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=PaGuw2CG  @NeilCoffey I would like a muffin; or an explanation of why decrementing for loops take so much longer than incrementing.  Either works :)    EDIT: I just switched the order to run the incrementing for loop first, and the times swapped.  First for loop is slow; second is fast; nevermind me.

Comment: @NeilCoffey What kind of muffin?  And is there a chance of a cup of coffee to go with it?

Comment: The JVM will probably unroll both loops anyway.

Comment: @Vulcan - repeat after me. "I must warm up the JVM before measuring".  You are most likely seeing an artifact of the JIT compilation process.

Comment: @alpha123 - on the contrary, it will quite likely optimize them to nothing.

Comment: @StephenC yes, but I was assuming there would actually be code in the loop.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [specification of the Java language](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/index.html) does not specify how long time certain statements will take to execute, so there is no answer to your question.

A smart enough compiler is free to compile both statements to a no-op and still be compliant. In fact, the JIT will most likely do so in both of these cases.

Comment: Um, I don't get this point. I'm pretty sure the JLS also doesn't specify whether `int i = 0; ++i;` takes longer than a bubble sort of a million Strings, but I'm very confident it wouldn't.

Comment: The bottom line is that witout further information about compiler, hardware, JVM (if the compiler previously mentioned even targets java bytecode), JIT compiler, ..., it is impossible to tell.

Comment: For something as close as the OP's question, I definitely agree. All I'm saying is that just because the JLS doesn't specify something, doesn't mean you can't reasonably make predictions about its performance characteristics. If the question had asked if incrementing an int is slower than sorting a million strings and writing them to disk, the JLS still doesn't specify how long each of those will take, but there's definitely an answer to that question in practice.

Comment: @yshavit - your argument is sound, but it doesn't help.  The real reasons we can't make any decent predictions is because of the variability and complexity of the optimizations that *might* be performed ... depending on the platform, JVM version and so on.

Comment: This answer is not helpful, a better answer to the same question can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8553468/confusion-on-loops-in-java?rq=1

Answer (score 5):

1. It is not possible to say which will be faster in general.  It depends on platforms, instruction sets, JIT compilers and so on.
2. This JIT compiler is likely to *completely* optimize the loop away ... in your examples ... because the loop body is empty, and the code obviously does not effect the overall computation.
3. Assuming that the real code doesn't have an empty loop, the actual loop body (and maybe what is before / after the loop) will strongly influence the code generated for the loop, and hence its performance.
4. Choosing one version over the other *probably* won't make a significant difference to the overall performance of your application.
5. If you still believe that this will make a difference, then code your application both ways, and test the *actual* performance.  But beware that the answer you get from testing will be different with different contexts for the code, different stuff in the loop body, different compilers, hardware and so on.  (And beware of the pitfalls of microbenchmarks in Java; e.g. the problem that @Vulcan had when he tried to measure the performance of your example code.)
6. Writing code in non-obvious / contorted ways *may* actually inhibit the JIT compiler's optimizer from producing optimal.  Optimizers are typically tuned to focus on code patterns that are likely to appear in typical programs.  Time spent looking for obscure code patterns that are rarely used just makes the JIT compiler slower.

---

The fact that you are asking this question suggests that you are making the mistake of "premature optimization".  Instead of wasting your time with this, write your code in a straight-forward fashion, get it working, and then profile it using real inputs.  Use the profiler output to guide you as to where it is *fruitful* to spend time hand optimizing.

Answer (score 2):

I highly doubt that this actually will impact the performance of your application.  [Premature optimization is the root of all evil.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize)

Use a [profiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_%28computer_programming%29) to find out where the bottlenecks are in your application before optimizing.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between increment and decrement is immaterial, however there could well be an important difference between these two when you take into account exactly what is being executed in the body of that loop -- and there's obviously no way to give any general statement about that.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it doesn't matter. They both perform the same way. Why? Well, there's something called Java Virtual Machine and I'm pretty sure is optimized to recognize both as the same sentence.